# Get Table A record if Table B has a match in a search

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE RetailGroup(
Id             int IDENTITY(1,1), 
GroupName      nvarchar(50),   
)     

CREATE TABLE RetailStore(
Id             int IDENTITY(1,1), 
StoreName      nvarchar(100),     
RetailGroupId  int  
)
```

Where RetailGroupId in RetailStore is referencing RetailGroup ID. I am trying to create a search function where I can search for both RetailGroup and RetailsStores. If I get a matching RetailStore I want to return the Group it is tied to and the matching Store record. If I get a matching Group, I want the group record but no retail stores.

I tried to do it the following way:

```
public List<RetailGroup> SearchGroupsAndStores(string value)
{
    return _context.RetailGroups.Where(group => group.GroupName.Contains(value)).Include(group => group.RetailStores.Where(store => store.StoreName.Contains(value))).ToList();
}
```

But this is wrong because include should not be used for selection.

Here is my entity framework model for groups

```
public class RetailGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { set; get; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String GroupName { set; get; }

    //Relations
    public ICollection<RetailStore> RetailStores { set; get; }
}
```

And here is the one for the store

```
public class RetailStore
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string StoreName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RetailGroup")]
    public int RetailGroupId { get; set; }

    //Relations
    public RetailGroup RetailGroup { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EGPLicense> Licenses { get; set; }
}
```

How do I create my `LINQ` to get the results I am looking for ?

Comment: IMO, trying to do two separate operations (find by store and find by group) should be split into two separate methods. If you still want one unified search option, you should use a third method and if/else call both smaller search methods to find what you want

Comment: I might need to do that. I searched a bit and it seems Conditional Include is not supported. I think I might just go old school and do a raw SQL call instead. I made a temporary fix that makes multiple calls to build the result one group and store at a time. Not the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query returning the desired result with projection is not hard:

```
var dbQuery = _context.RetailGroups
    .Select(rg => new
    {
        Group = rg,
        Stores = rg.RetailStores.Where(rs => rs.StoreName.Contains(value))
    })
    .Where(r => r.Group.GroupName.Contains(value) || r.Stores.Any());
```

The problem is that you want the result to be contained in the entity class, and EF6 neither supports projecting to entity types nor filtered includes.

To overcome these limitations, you can switch to LINQ to Objects context by using `AsEnumerable()` method, which at that point will effectively execute the database query, and then use delegate block to extract the entity instance from the anonymous type projection, bind the filtered collection to it and return it:

```
var result = dbQuery
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r =>
    {
        r.Group.RetailStores = r.Stores.ToList();
        return r.Group;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I think it's even enough to return `r.Group` after `AsEnumerable()` because relationship fixup will have populated `Group.RetailStores` (and it won't be repopulated by lazy loading because it's not virtual).

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `OR` condition to filter both the group name and the store name.

```
return _context.RetailGroups
    .Where(group => group.GroupName.Contains(value) || group.RetailStores.Any(store => store.StoreName.Contains(value)))
    .Include(group => group.RetailStores.Where(store => store.StoreName.Contains(value)))
    .ToList();
```

Another option would be doing 2 searches, one for the groups and other for the stores. The problem here would be geting a unique set of groups from both results.

```
List<RetailGroup> retailGroups = new List<RetailGroup>();

var groupSearchResults = _context.RetailGroups
    .Where(group => group.GroupName.Contains(value))
    .Include(group => group.RetailStores.Where(store => store.StoreName.Contains(value)))
    .ToList();

var storeSearchResults = _context.RetailStores
    .Where(store => store.StoreName.Contains(value))
    .Select(store => store.RetailGroup)
    .ToList();

retailGroups.AddRange(groupSearchResults);
retailGroups.AddRange(storeSearchResults); 

// Remove duplicates by ID
retailGroups = retailGroups
    .GroupBy(group => group.Id)
    .Select(group => group.First());
```

Comment: `Where` is not supported inside `Include`

Answer (score -1):

Either use `OR` condition and have the search in one statement :

```
public List<RetailGroup> SearchGroupsAndStores(string value)
{
    return _context.RetailGroups
    .Where(rg => rg.GroupName.Contains(value) || rg.RetailStores.Any(rs => rs.StoreName.Contains(value)))
    .Include(rg => rg.RetailStores.Where(rs => rs.StoreName.Contains(value)).ToList())
    .ToList();
}
```

Or you can split the search, first look for `RetailGroups` then search `RetailStores` and return their `RetailGroup` :

```
public List<RetailGroup> SearchGroupsAndStores(string value)
{
    List<RetailGroup> searchResults = new List<RetailGroup>();
    searchResults.AddRange(_context.RetailGroups.Where(rg => rg.GroupName.Contains(value)).ToList());
    searchResults.AddRange(_context.RetailStores.Where(rs => rs.StoreName.Contains(value)).Select(rs => rs.RetailGroup).ToList());
}
```

Comment: I can't do conditional includes with Entity framework. It's only for including referenced data like context.RetailGroup.Include(g => g.RetailsStores).someotheraction...

Comment: @evilfish use the second method then